# access class objects from other classes in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having problem implementing a solution to access my main class objects from another class without passing it as a parameter.

i have the following class:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'objectbox.g.dart'; // created by `flutter pub run build_runner build`

class ObjectBox {
  /// The Store of this app.
  late final Store store;

  ObjectBox._create(this.store) {
    // Add any additional setup code, e.g. build queries.
  }

  /// Create an instance of ObjectBox to use throughout the app.
  static Future<ObjectBox> create() async {
    final docsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // Future<Store> openStore() {...} is defined in the generated objectbox.g.dart
    final store = await openStore(directory: p.join(docsDir.path, "obx-example"));
    return ObjectBox._create(store);
  }
}
```

in my main.dart class i have the following (partial code):

```
late ObjectBox objectbox;

Future<void> main() async {
  // This is required so ObjectBox can get the application directory
  // to store the database in.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  objectbox = await ObjectBox.create();

  runApp(new MyHomePage( initialDate: DateTime.now()));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget  {
  final DateTime initialDate;

  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.initialDate}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>  {
  late DateTime selectedDate, prevSelectedDate;
  late String monthName1;
  late MonthYear monthYear;
  bool isSearch = false;
  double elevation = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedDate =  widget.initialDate;
  }
......
```

I have two other classes. lets called it class2 and class3. MyHomePage class calls class2 and class2 calls class3.  I would like to access the objectbox object in my MyHomePage class from class3 class without passing it as a parameter to class2 then to class3 and so on.

can someone help and provide sample code of how to do that?
thanks in advancd

Comment: what prevent you from accesing it if it is a global variable ?

Comment: not very familiar with flutter. so basically what you saying is to declare an object such as MyHomePage homepage = new MyHomePage ()  and then access it like this: homepage .objectbox

Answer (score 0):

I created a singleton class and then access the singleton from another class.